# How to hide scrollbar at initial display of screen?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a recyclerview and I added a scrollbar to it with the following code

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/white"
                android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade="500"
                android:scrollbarFadeDuration="500"
                >
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I would like if the scrollbar isn't displayed immediately when the screen that holds my recyclerview first comes to view. It should appear right when the user tries to scroll down and then fade out again. Right now, when I transition to this screen, the scrollbar is already displayed and once I scroll the screen down, then my scrollbar fades out. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you been googling about 'hide appbar on scroll android' ?

Comment: I don't want to hide my appbar. That is not the question I asked.

Comment: it is default feature of recycler view that u want to achieve, no need to fade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution to this. I wanted my scrollbar to not appear when the screen that contains my recycler view first comes into view. So I just added this

```
recyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); //hides scrollbar at the beginning
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                recyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                return false;
            }
});
```

so immediately when I want to scroll, the touch listener will display my scrollbar and setting the fade out options in the xml fades the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:fadeScrollbars="true"`
or make it false